# Sticky DIV in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the DIV with the `class="menu__overlay--bottom"` stick to the bottom always. I tried with 'absolute' positioning too but that's not working. Could you kindly help?

```js
$(".menu__link").click(function () {
      $("#menu__main").toggleClass("active");
      $("#menu__overlay").toggleClass("active");
      $(".menu__close").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.menu__overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.menu__overlay--main {
  position: relative;
}
.menu__overlay--content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.menu__overlay--content h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #455cbc;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu__overlay--content h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #858585;
}
.menu__overlay--content h3 span {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.menu__overlay a {
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu__overlay a:hover, .menu__overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.menu__overlay--list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu__overlay--list li {
  padding: 7px 0;
}
.menu__overlay--list li span {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.menu__overlay--bottom {
  background-color: #f1f6ff;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu__overlay--name {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
  background-image: linear-gradient(327deg, #445bbc, #3274bb);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.menu__overlay--bg.active {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  z-index: 1;
}
#menu__main {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 300px;
   left: -315px;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.30s ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.30s ease;
  -o-transition: 0.30s ease;
  transition: 0.30s ease;
  z-index: 999999;
}

 #menu__main.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  transform: translate(260px, 0px);
}
.menu__close {
  width: 100%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   -webkit-transition: 0.30s ease;
   -moz-transition: 0.30s ease;
   -o-transition: 0.30s ease;
   transition: 0.30s ease;  
}
.menu__close.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  transform: translate(260px, 0px);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu__close.active .menu__link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.menu__close.active .menu__link img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu__close">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#menu__main">
              MENU
            </a>
</div>
<nav id="menu__main" class="menu__overlay">
    <div class="menu__overlay--main">
      <div class="menu__overlay--content">
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Whatever contents are here.</p>
        <p>Whatever contents are here.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
        <p>Scrollable Menu.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="menu__overlay--bottom">
        Stick to bottom always
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it by doing the following:

```
.menu__overlay--content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#menu__main {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu__overlay--bottom {
    background-color: #f1f6ff;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 100px;
    height: 50px; /* Set a height for your bottom element */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu__overlay--content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
    /* Using calc deduct the height of your bottom content this way you can achive 
    100% full height of your content */
}
```

I hope this helps solve your issue.